# parallelization and synchronization with omp

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, synchronization, openmp, critical-section

Im trying to do the equivalent of this code with omp parallel and omp critical to synchronize it:

```
  std::vector<int> randValueCounter(int n, int listSize) {
   std::vector<int> list1(listSize, 0);
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
     int rand = randomVal();
     if(rand <= listSize){
        ++list1[rand]
     
   }
  
   return list1;
 }
```

my attempt to use prallelization + synchronization using OMP parallel and OMP critical:

```
  std::vector<int> randValueCounter2(int n, int listSize) {
   std::vector<int> list1(listSize, 0);

   #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      int rand = randomVal();
      #pragma omp critical
      {
      if(rand <= listSize){
         ++list1[rand]
      }
    }
   
    return list1;
 }
```

I read that randValueCounter2 will have some overhead, but I was wondering if it in this case would accumulate the same result in functionality as the first function ?

Comment: How complicated is `randomVal`? Is it thread safe? The critical bit will be a bottleneck. It could be improved slightly by moving the critical after the `if` to just cover the `++list1[rand]`, but you might be better off having each thread have its own list to increment then combine them all when your loop is done (possibly with a `reduction` clause).

Comment: To complete the answer of 1201ProgramAlarm, the current code will not scale because of the critical section, and the parallel code will actually even be likely slower due to the lock contention between multiple cores.

Comment: If `randomVal` is threadsafe, then you will obtain similar result. To complete @1201ProgramAlarm's suggestion to define reduction write `#pragma omp declare reduction(vec_int_plus : std::vector<int> : std::transform(omp_out.begin(), omp_out.end(), omp_in.begin(), omp_out.begin(), std::plus<int>())) initializer(omp_priv = omp_orig)` and use `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(vec_int_plus : List1)` then you can remove the critical section, but the performance gain is still questionable.